# Asynchronous data retrieving and rendering in ExtJS with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, extjs, callback

so I have this situation:

```
renderer: function(value, grid, record) {
                  var testAjax = function(callback) {
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                      url: appConfig.baseUrl + '/api/users/' + record.getData().id + '/jobRoles',
                      method: 'GET',
                      success: function(result) {
                        callback(result)
                      };
                    });
                  };
                  return testAjax(function(result) {
                    try {
                      result = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
                    } catch(e) {
                      return '';
                    }
                    result = result.data;
                    var roles = _.map(result, function(jRole) {
                      console.log(jRole);
                      return jRole.name;
                    }).join(',');
                    console.log("Roles: ", roles);
                    return roles;
                  });
                }
```

What I wanted to achieve is that when I have to render a particular field, I make a call to my Loopback endpoint, retrieve some data about a relation, map it using a "," character and return the joined string in order to view it.

However, I think I have a few problem with callbacks here as I don't see the result at all, as if the function is returning before the callback is called (thus showing nothing instead of what I retrieved from the server).

I tried to look here and there, and this is the best I came up with.

How can I return to the parent function the "roles" variable? How do I properly set up my callbacks?

Regards

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to load all the job roles in a store, and then look them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot and should not use the renderer with load operations and asynchonous callbacks. The renderer can be called dozens of times for the same record, if you filter or sort or just refresh the grid view. What you want to do is get all the information required for display in the grid in a single call. Data you cannot get in the single call should not be shown in the grid. You don't want to call the endpoint 1000 times for 1000 records, because even if each call needs only 60ms, that's a full minute.

That said, if you really have to, because you cannot change the endpoints and the roles have to be displayed, you can do as follows:

```
dataIndex: 'MyTempRoles',
renderer: function(value, grid, record) {
    if(value) return value; // show the loaded value if available
    else { // no value loaded -> load value
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: appConfig.baseUrl + '/api/users/' + record.getData().id + '/jobRoles',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                try {
                    result = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
                    result = result.data;
                    var roles = _.map(result, function(jRole) {
                        console.log(jRole);
                        return jRole.name;
                    }).join(',');
                    record.set("MyTempRoles", roles || " "); // put the loaded value into the record. This will cause a grid row refresh, thus a call to the renderer again.
                } catch(e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will call the backend in the first call to the renderer, and asynchronously fill the displayed record's temp variable. When the temp variable is filled, the renderer will then display the value from the temp variable automatically.

Comment: That worked like a charm!
Also thanks for lecturing me about renderer event, I thought it was called once on display, will look more into it :)

Comment: Open https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23nu, open browser console and just scroll down and up the grid. You will find that the renderer is called really often.