# Extjs: How to set iconCls for actioncolumn using response data of ajax

Tags: extjs

Hi I am trying to display icons using iconCls of actioncolumn as in below code:

```
xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                    header: moment().utc().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMM Do'),
                    itemId: 'cDayOne',
                    align: 'center',
                    dataIndex: 'Day1Status',
                    renderer: function (v, metadata, record) {
                        var c = this;
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: url to fetch data,
                            method: 'GET',
                            success: function (response) {
                                if (result.status_time_diff === 0) {
                                    c.tdCls = 'green';
                                } else if (result.status_time_diff < 3) {
                                    c.iconCls = 'yellow';
                                } else if (result.status_time_diff > 4) {
                                    c.iconCls = 'red';
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

The above code is not working with ajax call, if I remove the ajax call and assin c.iconCls = 'green'(any hardcoded value) it is working fine.

Can someone help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a  iconCls from an asynchronous function. Call your ajax endpoint before creating `grid` component

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the approach given in below link. It worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170693/asynchronous-data-retrieving-and-rendering-in-extjs-with-ajax

Comment: interesting method.